# A precise statement of $\omega\cdot t = \theta$?

Tags: vectors, circles, classical-mechanics

In my course notes on constant circular motion, I have the equation
\begin{align}
\omega\cdot t=\theta,\tag{1}
\end{align}
where

- $\omega$ is angular velocity;
- $t$ is time;
- $\theta$ is angle.

Would it be fair to say that this is a short-hand for the following?
\begin{cases}
\overrightarrow{\omega(t)}\cdot t&=\overrightarrow{\phi(t)},\\
\Big|\overrightarrow{\phi(t)}\Big|&\equiv_{2\pi}\theta,\tag{2}
\end{cases}

where

- $\overrightarrow{\omega(t)}$ is angular velocity, a vector and a function of time;
- $t$ is time, a scalar;
- $\overrightarrow{\phi(t)}$ is angular displacement, a vector and a function of time;
- $\theta$ is angular position, a scalar, the principal residue of the absolute value of $\overrightarrow{\phi(t)}\text{ (mod } 2\pi)$.

Comment: It looks OK. At least for positive $t$. Is there a reason you want to do it this way?

Comment: @Andrei I guess the main part is the relationship between $\theta$ and $\phi(t)$. If the fuller statement is correct, then strictly speaking the shorter one is incorrect, and I wanted to see if that's right. If it's a short-hand, that's fine as long as I know.

Comment: This may be apropos: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233499/22581

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, this looks good, thanks. So if $\overrightarrow{\theta}$ and $\overrightarrow{2\pi^{\text{rad}}}$ are vectors then the absolute value step is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

***Absolutely not.***

Your $\overrightarrow{\phi(t)}$ has a *direction* and that direction is unrelated to $\phi$.  More importantly, with traditional vectors you can simply change the origin and all the vectors by an offset vector and the equations all remain valid.  Not so with your hypothesis.

If you change the origin, how does $\overrightarrow{\phi(t)}$ change?

Vectors add (component by component).  Try your definition on adding the three angles (starting from the purple dot) defined by these arcs to see the obvious contradictions.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following. Would you mind spelling it out a little more?

Comment: What is the "direction" of your vector for the $90^\circ$ angle swept out by the green arc?  Repeat for the red and blue.  How would you "add" these angles?  What does that mean about the beginning and end of the arcs?

Comment: If all three vectors go in the anti-clockwise direction, then adding the red and blue arcs nose-to-tail picks out the same point as the green arc. Since the question was about circular motion, the blue and red arcs would lie on the green one, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are very confused about the difference between a (scalar) *angle* and a (vector) *displacement*.

Comment: Here's my understanding: an angular displacement (vector) is the result of taking an angle (scalar) and giving it a direction. The vector-scalar distinction is actually the motivation for the question, since it looks to me like $\omega\cdot t=\theta$ equates a vector (the product of angular velocity, a vector, with time, a scalar) to a scalar (angle).